# Trying to assigm optimal weights to a set of sensors, when their noises may change levels through time.

Tags: kalman-filter

The Kalman Filter is useful for combining measurements from different sensors with possibly different levels of noise. However, in practice, one must estimate the level of noise of each sensor to come close to giving optimal weights to each. When these noises are constant, that is one thing. But another thing is when the noise of different sensors can change.

My question is the following. How would you assign optimal weights to a set of sensors, when their noises may change levels (and when such level-changes must be detected).

Answer (score 0):

The Kalman Filter for adjusting the process and measurement covariances online is referred to as the Adaptive Kalman Filter. There are multiple variations, and I believe most focus on adjusting the $Q$ matrix (process covariance), but works exist for adjusting the $R$ matrix (measurement covariance).

These approaches don't seek to "detect" if the noise changes, but instead, the covariance matrices are updated based on the innovation covariance $S$.

I'm not too familiar with the Adaptive Kalman Filter, so I can't provide more details on the approach, but there is indeed a lot of research on this topic, and this is the keyword you will want to use for searching for additional details.